# Divisibility: Remainders and Greatest Common Divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)$ when $a = qb + r$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95799/why-is-gcda-b-gcdb-r-when-a-qb-r)

Any idea how to prove that if $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ with $b = aq + r$, then $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a,r)$?

Comment: **HINT** Note that any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ divides $r$. (Why?) Similarly, any common divisor of $a$ and $r$ divides $b$. (Why?)

Comment: Prove $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-a)$, then invoke induction.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $k$ divides both $a$ and $b$ if and only if it divides both $a$ and $b+ta$ for any $t$. (Prove that if it divides $a$ and $b$ then it divides $a$ and $b+ta$. The converse follows by applying the argument again to $a$ and $b+ta$ to get $a$ and $(b+ta)+(-t)a$.

Now, if $b=aq+r$ then we have:
$$\begin{align*}
k|a,b &\iff k|a,b+a(-q)\\
&\iff k|a,r
\end{align*}$$
So the set of common divisors of $a$ and $b$ and the set of common divisors of $a$ and $r$ coincides.