# Proof about gcd and remainders

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)$ when $a = qb + r$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95799/why-is-gcda-b-gcdb-r-when-a-qb-r)

Prove: $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a+bq, b)$

Proof:

By the division algorithm we know:

$a = b\cdot q + r \iff r = a -b\cdot q$

Thus, we see it is equivalent to prove $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(b, r)$

To me the claim seems straight forward, since the term $a+bq$ in the $\gcd(a+bq, b)$ is "dependent" on the $a$. That is, $\gcd(bq, b) = b$, so adding an $a$ really determines the $\gcd(a+bq, b)$.

How can I formalize this and use more mathematical terms?

Comment: You've got two different uses of $q$. The $q$ from the division algorithm is different from the $q$ from $(a+bq,b)$.

Comment: Division algorithm says there are integers $x,y$ with $a=bx+y$ with $0\leq y<b$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest proving the result like this:

(i) Show that if $x$ divides $a$ and $b$, then $x$ divides $a+bq$ and $b$.

(ii) Show that if $x$ divides $a+bq$ and $b$, then $x$ divides $a$ and $b$.

Once you have done this, you will have shown that the **set** of common divisors of $a$ and $b$ is the same as the set of common divisors of $a+bq$ and $b$.

From this the result should follow easily. The final details depend on your official definition of $\gcd$. If, as is likely in your course, it is defined as the *largest* common divisor, then the result follows immediately. For since the sets of common divisors are the same, their largest element must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\rm\:c\:|\:b\:$ then $\rm\: c\:|\:a\iff c\:|\:a\!+\!b\,q.\:$ Thus $\rm\:a,\,b\:$ and $\rm\:a\!+\!b\,q,\,b\:$ have the same set C of common divisors $\rm\:c,\:$ hence they have the same *greatest* common divisor (= max C). $\ $ **QED**

Or: $\rm\: mod\ c\!:\ if\ \ b\equiv 0\ \ then \ \ a\equiv 0\iff a+b\,q\equiv 0,\ $ using congruence language.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy to show that two positive integers are equal is to show that they divide each other. This is common in number theory.

Let $a, b, q\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $d_1=gcd(a+bq, b)$ and $d_2=gcd(a,b)$. We show that $d_1\mid d_2$ and $d_2\mid d_1$; thus showing they are equal.

Since $d_1=gcd(a+bq, b)$ we have that $d_1\mid b$ and $d_1\mid a+bq$ but since $d_1\mid b$ we have $d_1\mid bq$ thus $d_1\mid a$ (You can show this by writing down the congruence). Since $d_1\mid a$ and $d_1\mid b$ we have $d_1\mid d_2$.

Since $d_2=gcd(a,b)$ we have $d_2\mid b$ and $d_2\mid a$. Since $d_2\mid b$ we have $d_2\mid bq$ and hence $d_2\mid a+bq$ and $d_2\mid b$ hence $d_2\mid d_1$.