# Prove GCD(a, a-1)=1

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've seen the typical proof for GCD(a, a+1) = 1.

But how do you do this for GCD(a, a-1) = 1?

a must be a positive integer throughout the proof.

For example, the GCD for 6 and 7 is 1. For every consecutive numbers paired together, this is the case because a = 2k and a+1 = 2k +1. I think I'm getting somewhere...

Another thing to note is that we cannot use P, because a or a+1 is not always a prime number.

Comment: Hint: If $p|a$ and $p|b$ ,then $p|a-b$. Furthermore, if you just change "$a$" to "$a-1$", then $\gcd(a,a+1)=1$ changes to $\gcd(a-1,a)=1$, which is what you wanted.

Comment: The answer below says precisely what I wanted to say. $p$ was an ordinary number, not a prime, but that's my fault. Of course, GCD does not depend on order? The gcd of $a,b$ is the gcd of $b,a$, because the greatest common divisor is defined in a symmetric manner: it doesn't give precedence to either $a$ or $b$ in the definition.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to add one to the other side too, to make it = 2??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that for any integer $k \ne 0$, $\gcd(k, k+1) = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231887/prove-that-for-any-integer-k-ne-0-gcdk-k1-1)

Answer (score 3):

Let $d$ be the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $a-1$. Notice that it must divide $a-(a-1)$ and so $d$ divides $1$. We are done.

Comment: Oh, one thing though, how did you get that it must divide a - (a-1)?

Comment: if any number, say $x$ divides another two numbers, say $a$ and $b$ then $x$ must also divide their difference. In other words $x$ must divide $a-b$.