# Why is $\gcd(44m+15;15m+5) = \gcd(m;5)$?

Tags: calculus, divisibility, integers, gcd-and-lcm

I was solving a math problem and the book at some point wrote that

$$\gcd(44m+15;15m+5) = \gcd(m;5)$$ when $m$ is an integer.

Why?

Comment: $$-(44m+15)+3(15m+5)=m\\ 15(44m+15)-44(15m+5)=5.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I might be stupid but isn't this incorrect? The property says  $gcd(n,m)=gcd(n−km,m)$ right? However, as an example, here it's no longer $n-km$ since you multiplied each side by a number not only one. so it's more like $an-km$ right now

Comment: That wasn't what I was hinting at with my comment. If $ax+by=d,$ then $\gcd(a,b)\mid d.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But the property I wrote works just as fine, right?

Comment: Use the reduction step of the Euclidean algorithm to continually reduce the coef's of $m$, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/239251/242) in the first dupe for a similar gcd calculation.

Comment: **Or** $\,(\color{#c00}{44}m+\color{#0a0}{15},\,\color{#0a0}3m+\color{#c00}1)=1\,$ by $\,\color{#0a0}{15(3)}-\color{#c00}{44(1)}=1\,$ and the formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1911382/242), so Euclid's Lemma $\,\Rightarrow (44m+15,\,5(3m+1) = (\color{#90f}{44m+15},5) = (\color{#90f}{-m},5) = (m,5)\,$ by $\,\color{#90f}{(44m+15)\bmod\color{#000}{5} = -m}\,$ and [gcd modular reduction,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) i.e. the descent step of the Euclidean algorithm. $\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\gcd(44m+15, 15m+5)=\gcd(-m,15m+5)=\gcd(-m, 5)=\gcd(m,5)$$

The first equalities derive from the property of the gcd that states: $\gcd(n,m)=\gcd(n-km, m)$, where $k$ is an integer. The last equality is trivial since the divisors of $m$ are the same as the divisors of $-m$.

Comment: Ummm how did you get $-m$ from that though?

Comment: It’s worth stating the underlying result you are using.

Comment: @TechnoKnight By using the division algorithm.  For $a \lt b$, it's always the case that $\gcd (a, b)=\gcd(a, r)$, where $r$ is the remainder of $\frac ba$.

Comment: @RobertShore umm thanks I think I got it now!

Comment: @RobertShore So for the first two equalities, you just divided b by a then calculated the reminder right? So $44m+15 / 15m+5$ and you found $-m$ then $15m+5/-m$ and you found 5, right?

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).