# CHECK: Let a and b be relatively prime integers. Show that $\gcd(a^2+b^2,a+b)=$1 or 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Let a and b be relatively prime integers. Show that $\gcd(a^2+b^2,a+b)=$1 or 2

Proof:
$s|a^2+b^2$ and $s|a+b$ implies $s|a^2+b^2$ and $s|(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$ implies
$s|a^2+b^2-(a+b)^2=2ab$ implies $s|2a$ and $s|2b$ implies $s|\gcd(2a,2b)=2gcd(a,b)=2*1$

Hence $\gcd(a^2+b^2,a+b)=1 or 2$

Comment: In $s\mid 2ab\implies s\mid 2a\land s\mid 2b$, consider $a=3,b=1$ and $s=4$.

Comment: @GitGud Summer is upon us and my brain has already shut off.

Comment: @GammaFunction I'll join you in 20 days.

Comment: Remember that you can also use this strategy: after you find out that $s\mid 2ab$, you can prove that $s\mid 2$. Suppose that $s\mid ab$. Then either $s\mid a$ or $s\mid b$. But since $s\mid a+b$, we would have $\begin{cases}s\mid a\implies s\mid b\\ s\mid b\implies s\mid a\end{cases}$, but $\gcd(a,b)=1$, so that is a contradiction $\implies$ hence $s\mid 2$. That is in case you haven't figured that out on your own so far.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod}\ a\!+\!b\!:\,\ a\equiv -b\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{a^2\!+\!b^2\equiv 2b^2}\,$ so, by the Euclidean Algorithm $\rm\color{#c00}{(EA)}$

$\quad (a\!+\!b,\,\color{#0a0}{a^2\!+\!b^2})\overset{\rm\color{#c00}{EA}} = (a\!+\!b,\,\color{#0a0}{2b^2}) = (a\!+\!b,\,2)\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \Bigg\{ \begin{eqnarray} &&(a\!+\!b,b)\overset{\rm\color{#c00}{EA}}= (a,b)=1\\  \Rightarrow &&(a\!+\!b,b^2) = 1\end{eqnarray}\ \,$ by Euclid.

Here $\rm\color{#c00}{EA}$ means $\ (m,n)\, =\, (m,n')\ $ if $\ n'\!\equiv n\pmod m\,\ $  [= descent step of Euclidean Algorithm].

**Remark** $\ $ More generally one [may prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/307700/242) $\ (a\!+\!b,\ a^2\!+\!b^2)\, =\,(a\!+\!b,\,2(a,b)^2)\ $ for all $\,a,b\in\Bbb Z.$

Comment: Or, by applying the Euclidean Algorithm in the manner you showed  [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/810531/85660), which gives $(a+b, a^2 + b^2) = (a + b, 2)$

Comment: @Anant Yes, that was the intended answer, but somehow I mistakenly pasted an answer from another question I was working on. Time to clean out the gunk under my keyboard keys, which apparently nullified the copy (Ctrl+C) preceding the paste. Good thing you noticed that. Now fixed, with a link to a generalization.

Comment: I see absolutely no problem! It was an instructive answer.

Answer (score 0):

We use a result that can be proven fairly easily and in fact has already been posted here at MSE. But let's assume we haven't seen this post, and try to rediscover it...

**claim:** If $gcd(a,b) = 1$, then $gcd(a-b,a+b) = 1$ or $2$. This you can prove.

If $d = gcd(a-b,a+b)$, then if $d > 1$, you need to prove $d = 2$. If $d$ is odd, then $d|(a+b) + (a-b) = 2a$, and $d|(a+b) - (a-b) = 2b$, then $d|a$, and $d|b$, and then $d|(a,b) = 1$. So $d = 1$, contradiction. Thus $d$ is even, and write $d = 2d'$, then: $2d'|2a$, and $2d'|2b$ implying $d'|a$, and $d'|b$. So: $d'|(a,b) = 1$. Thus $d' = 1$, and this gives $d = 2d' = 2\times 1 = 2$.

Using this claim, we divide the problem in $2$ cases:

**Case 1:** $gcd(a-b,a+b) = 1$, then we need to prove: $gcd(a+b,a^2 + b^2) = 1$.

Let $d = gcd(a+b,a^2+b^2)$, then $d|a+b$, so $d|(a+b)^2$. But $d|a^2 + b^2$, so $d|(a+b)^2 - (a^2+b^2) = 2ab = (a^2+b^2) - (a-b)^2$. So: $d|(a-b)^2$. Thus: $d|gcd((a-b)^2,(a+b)^2) = 1^2 = 1$. Thus: $d = 1$.

**Case 2:** $gcd(a-b,a+b) = 2$, then we prove: $d = gcd(a+b,a^2 + b^2) = 2$.

Then $a-b = 2m$, and $a+b = 2n$ with $m$, and $n$ are integers such that $gcd(m,n) = 1$. Then using the above argument in case 1, $d|gcd(4m^2,4n^2) = 4\cdot gcd(m^2,n^2) = 4\cdot 1^2 = 4$. So if:

a) $d = 1$, then case 1 gives $1 = gcd(a+b,(a-b)^2) = gcd(2n, (2m)^2) = 2\cdot gcd(n,2m^2) \geq 2$. Contradiction.

b) $d = 4$, then $4|a+b$, and $4|a^2 + b^2$. This means both $a$ and $b$ must be even. So: $a = 2k$, and $b = 2s$. So: $a - b = 2(k - s)$, and $a + b = 2(k + s)$, and $2 = gcd(a-b,a+b) = gcd(2(k-s), 2(k+s)) = 2\cdot gcd(k-s,k+s)$. So: $gcd(k-s,k+s) = 1$. Also:

$4 = gcd(a+b,a^2+b^2) = gcd(2(k+s),4k^2 + 4s^2) = 2\cdot gcd(k+s,2(k^2+s^2))$. Thus:

$2 = gcd(k+s,2(k^2+s^2))$.

But from case 1 apply to $k$, and $s$ we have: $gcd(k-s,k+s) = 1 \to gcd(k+s, k^2+s^2) = 1$ . But $2|k+s$, means that $k+s$ is even, which implies $k^2 + s^2 = (k+s)^2 - 2ks$ is also even. So we can let $k+s = 2p$, and $k^2+s^2 = 2q$. Then: $1 = gcd(k+s,k^2+s^2) = gcd(2p,2q) = 2\cdot gcd(p,q) \geq 2$. Contradiction again.

So: $d = 2$, completing the proof.