# If $a = r \pmod b$ when $0 \le r < b$, then $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd (b, r)$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

If $a = r \pmod b$ when $0 \le  r < b$, then $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd (b, r)$.

I do not understand why this is, can somebody explain?

I've also looked over this thread: [Why is $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)$ when $a = qb + r$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95799/why-is-gcda-b-gcdb-r-when-a-qb-r) , but I still can't seem to see how that applies to $a = r \pmod b$.

Comment: $ a = r (mod\ b) $ is same as $ a = qb + r $.

Comment: How are they equal?

Comment: Please read [this wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) thoroughly.