# Proof for: GCD and divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I need some hints how to proof something like the following:

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a,b \not= 0$ and let $\gcd(a,b)=d$.

(1) For any $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $d \mid ma+nb$.

(2) There exist $t,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $d = ta + rb$.

Thank you very much for any help ;)

Comment: For the second one, it's Bézout's lemma. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity

Answer (score 1):

$(1)\,$ follows by basic divisibility laws: for *any* $\,d\in\Bbb Z\!:\ d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid\,\color{#0a0}ma,\color{#0a0}nb\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid ma\color{#c00}+nb.\,$ Said equivalently, the set of multiples of $d$ are closed under integer $\rm\color{#0a0}{scalings}$, and under $\color{#c00}{\rm addition}$ (the same holds true for the set of *common* multiples of any set of integers).  Or, for a direct proof: $\, a = \bar a d,\, b = \bar b d\, $ so $\, ma + nb = m\bar a d + n\bar b d = (m\bar a + n\bar b) d\,$ is a multiple of $d$.

This *linear* structure of a set of (common) multiples of an integer lies at the heart of many divisibility results. This innate linear structure is brought to the fore when one studies [ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)) in rings, as well as [modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)) - a generalization of a vector space with scalarsfrom rings (vs. fields).

$(2)\,$ can be proved by (complete) induction, using the basic [descent step of the Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) for the gcd, that the gcd remains the same if we subtract the smaller argument from the larger one, i.e $\ \gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a,b\!-\!a).\,$ If $\,0 < a < b\,$ then $\,a+(b\!-\!a) < a+b,\,$  so, by complete induction on the height $\,:= a+b\,$ of $\,\gcd(a,b),\,$ we conclude that $\,d = m a + n(b-a)\,$ for some $\,m,n\in\Bbb Z,\,$ But, rearranging, $\,d  = (m-n)a + nb\,$ is also a linear combination of $\,a,b.\,$ QED $ $ That's a sketch of the inductive proof of the Bezout Identity for the gcd. You need to fill in  details, e.g. base case(s).

**Remark** $\ $ Interpreted *constructively*, the above yields an *extended* Euclidean algorithm that computes the gcd linear Bezout representation. For efficiency we can replace the above subtractive descent by its iteration to modular form $\,\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a,b\!-\!qa) = \gcd(b,\, b\ {\rm mod}\ a).$ If we annotate the remainder sequence with equations expressing each remainder as a linear rep of $\,a,b\,$ then we obtain a very simple extended gcd algorithm, which is conveniently expressed in terms of *row operations* (as in linear algebra). This is both easier and far less error-prone than the alternative method of back-substitution. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) for complete details.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hints:}$

For (1), try to prove that $d$ divides both $ma$ and $nb$.

For (2), use the Euclidean algorithm to find $d$ and follow the algorithm in reverse direction to write $d$ as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$.