# How to find the LCM of numbers with exponents?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I would like to know if there is a mathematical approach to finding the LCM of 
$(29^{17} +2 , 29^{17} -1)$?

Even if we would rearrange it to a fraction of the form
$\frac{(29^{17} +2)\cdot (29^{17} -1)}{gcd(29^{17} +2 , 29^{17} -1)}$ ,
we would still need to calculate the GCD. Is there a way using number theory that I am missing? I dont want to resort to using calculator to figure this one out.

If its not possible to find the LCM, is it possible to find just it's unit digit?

Comment: Have you tried the Euclidean algorithm to find the $\gcd$?

Comment: @Arthur no i haven't tried it. Since this question has been posed using exponents, is there a way to capitalize on that? Does the fact that $29$ is raised to the power of $17$ help in calculating the LCM or GCD? Ecuclidean algorithm requires me to first solve $29^{17}$ and then use the numbers obtained to calculate the GCD

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm requires no such thing. It just requires you to calculate $29^{17}+2-(29^{17}-1)$.

Comment: @Arthur I'm surprised you got the GCD by just subtracting both the numbers. Can u explain a little? I thought Euclidean algo was like say u wanted LCM(30,27) , you would write $30=1\cdot27 + 3$ and then proceed with $27$ and $3$ and on.

Comment: Move $1\cdot 27$ over to the other side of the equality sign, and you will have $30-27 = 3$. That's the subtraction I'm referring to. Now do it with your two numbers instead of $30$ and $27$.

Comment: Oh ok. I'll try to first find the GCD and then solve for LCM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let do this:
$$(29^{17}+2,29^{17}-1) = (29^{17}+2 - 29^{17}+1, 29^{17}-1) = (3,29^{17}-1)$$
$$29^{17}-1 \overset{3}{\equiv} (-1)^{17}-1 \overset{3}{\equiv} -1-1 \overset{3}{\equiv} -2$$
$$\Longrightarrow (29^{17}+2,29^{17}-1) = (3,29^{17}-1) = (3,-2) = 1$$
Now you can continue your way.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\, \gcd(a\!+\!3,a) =\!\!\!\!\overbrace{ \gcd(3,a)}^{\large \gcd(\color{#c00}{3,\,29^{17}-1})}\!\!\! $ by [subtractive](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/714409/242) Euclid algorithm (subtract least from largest arg)

Finally note that: $\bmod \color{#c00}{3}\!:\ \underbrace{\color{#c00}{29^{17}\!-\!1}\equiv (-1)^{17}\!-1}_{\textstyle{29\ \equiv\ -1\ \ }}\equiv -2\not\equiv 0\ $ by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).