# Prove that every prime larger than $3$ gives a remainder of $1$ or $5$ if divided by $6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Can we prove that every prime larger than $3$ gives a remainder of $1$ or $5$ if
divided by $6$ and if so, which formulas can be used while proving?

Comment: You mean "gives a remainder of 1 or 5 if divided by 6". Note that every other remainder (0, 2, 3, or 4) implies that either 2 or 3 will divide the number, so it isn't prime.

Comment: I guess it is. But in book page, it is written like "1 and -1"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes:

- $N \equiv 0 \pmod 6 \implies N$ is divisible by $6 \implies$ $N$ is not a prime
- $N \equiv 2 \pmod 6 \implies N$ is divisible by $2 \implies$ $N$ is not a prime (or $N=2$)
- $N \equiv 3 \pmod 6 \implies N$ is divisible by $3 \implies$ $N$ is not a prime (or $N=3$)
- $N \equiv 4 \pmod 6 \implies N$ is divisible by $2$ and $N\geq4 \implies$ $N$ is not a prime
- $N$ is a prime larger than $3 \implies N \not\equiv 0,2,3,4 \pmod 6 \implies N \equiv 1,5 \pmod 6$

Comment: Thank you! It is useful for me.

Comment: @A.D: You're welcome.

Comment: That's one heck of an optimization and one, nice, simple, proof for those of us that are not mathematicians.  This works an incredible performance treat using simple integer math in SQL.  Here's the link where a friend of mine used that optimization.  https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/calculating-prime-numbers-with-one-query/page/5#post-4215596

Answer (score 12):

HINT:

Every positive integer can be written as $$6n,6n\pm1,6n\pm2=2(3n\pm1),6n+3=3(2n+1)$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $ $ [By Euclid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) $\ (n,\,6) = (n\ {\rm mod}\ 6,\,6).\,$ Yours is special case $\,(n,6)=1,\,$ e.g. prime $\,n>3.$

So integers coprime to $\,6\,$ have residues (mod $6)\,$ that are coprime to $\,6,\,$ i.e. $\,1$ or $\,5\pmod{\! 6}.$

**Generally** if $\,n\,$ is coprime to $\,m\,$ then so too is its remainder $\,n\bmod m,\,$ so the remainder must be one of the $\phi(m)$ residues coprime to $m$, because the gcd remains unchanged upon applying a single descent step of the Euclidean algorithm for the gcd (proved in the prior linked post). In the OP we have $\,\phi(2\cdot 3) = 1\cdot 2$.

Answer (score 0):

A proof without word :
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \textbf1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \textbf5 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\
 18& 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 &  23\\
24 & \color{red}{25} & 26 & 27 & 28 &  29\\
30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & \color{red}{35} \\
 36& 37 & 38 & 39 &  40& 41 \\
 42& 43 &  44& 45 & 46 & 47 \\
 48& \color{red}{49} & 50 &  51& 52 & 53 \\
 54&  \color{red}{55}&56  &57  & 58 & 59\\..&..&..&..&..&..
\end{bmatrix}$