# Division algorithm on odd numbers

Tags: number-theory

Prove that every odd integer is of the form ${4k + 1}$ or ${4k+3}$.

I have to use division algorithm to prove it but I am unable to construct a proof. Please help. 
Thank you! :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every integer can be expressed as one of $$4n\equiv0\pmod2,$$
$$4n+1\equiv1\pmod2,$$
$$4n+2=2(2n+1)\equiv0\pmod2$$ and
$$4n+3\equiv1\pmod2$$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Yes! But I think that is what I have to prove that how odd integers are of the form ${4n +3}$. :)

Comment: @AbirMukherjee, You have to prove that $4n+1,4n+3$ are not divisible by $2$.  See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756547/proof-about-prime-numbers

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ 2n\!+\!1 = 4k\!+\!1 $ if $\,n=2k\,$ is even; $ $ else $\,n=2k\!+\!1\,$ is odd so  $\,2n\!+\!1 =\, \ldots$

**Remark** $\ $This applies the division algorithm to $\,n,\,$ not $\,2n\!+\!1.\,$ If you prefer the latter, then by division we can write it  in the form $\,4k\!+\!r\,$ for $\,r\in\{0,1,2,3\},\,$ and $\,4k\!+\!r\,$ odd $\,\Rightarrow\,r\,$ odd.