# Why is $(3,1+\sqrt{-5})^2=(2-\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I want to show $(3,1+\sqrt{-5})^2=(2-\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. It's easy to see $(2-\sqrt{-5})\subset (3,1+\sqrt{-5})^2$ since $2-\sqrt{-5}=3-(1+\sqrt{-5})$ is in $(3,1+\sqrt{-5})^2$. But I have difficulty proving the converse inclusion.

$(3,1+\sqrt{-5})^2=(3)(3)+(3)(1+\sqrt{-5})+(1+\sqrt{-5})^2=(3)(3,1+\sqrt{-5})+(2)(2-\sqrt{-5})$. How should I proceed?

Comment: I can't see how $a-b\in(a,b)^2$. So you seem to have difficulties with both containments.

Comment: @user26857: True, but his expansion on the next to last line does give that: $2(2-\sqrt{-5})$ is in there as are all multiples of $3$. In particular $3(2-\sqrt{-5})$. As the difference of those two you do get the claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below we *derive* it (vs. *check* it) using simple Euclidean-like reductions, i.e. by reducing some generators mod another (i.e. [ideal unimodular transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863501/242)  generalizing Euclidean algorithm).

Write $\ \overbrace{w = \sqrt{-5}}^{\large w^2\ =\ -5},\ $ so $\ I = (3,w\!+\!1)^2 = (3^2,\,\overbrace{(w\!+\!1)^2}^{\large \color{blue}{2w\,-\,4}\ \ },\,3(w\!+\!1))$

$ 9\in I\,\Rightarrow\, I = (9,\, I\:\!\ {\rm mod}\:\!\ 9),\ $ and $\,\ {\rm mod}\ 9\!:\ \color{blue}{2(w\!-\!2)}\equiv 0\!\! \overset{\large \times\,5\!}\iff \color{#0a0}{w\!-\!2}\equiv 0$

So $\, I = (\color{#c00}9, \color{#0a0}{w\!-\!2}, 3(w\!+\!1)) = \underbrace{(9,w\!-\!2,\color{#c00} 0)}_{\large \text{as claimed}},\,$ by $\, 3(w\!+\!1)\!\!\underset{\color{#0a0}{\large w\,\equiv\, 2^{\phantom{|^.}\!\!}}}\equiv\!\! 3(\color{#0a0}{3})\equiv\color{#c00}{9\equiv0}$

Comment: Deriving a result of a calculation has its purposes. As does the ability to pick up a student's incomplete argument and run with it. All roads lead to Rome and all that :-)

Answer (score 2):

Adding the simplest proof I could come up with here:

The ideal $P=(3,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is one of the prime ideals lying above the rational prime $3$, and of index three in the ring of integers.
By multiplicativity of indices of ideals we have 
$$
[\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]:P^2]=9.
$$
Combining this with the fact 
$$[\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]:(2-\sqrt{-5})]=N(2-\sqrt{-5})=2^2+5\cdot(-1)^2=9,$$ your observation
that $(2-\sqrt{-5})\subseteq P^2$ and multiplicativity of index in a tower of abelian groups:
$$
9=[\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]:(2-\sqrt{-5})]= [\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]:P^2]\cdot =[P^2:(2-\sqrt{-5})]
$$
imply that $[P^2:(2-\sqrt{-5})]=1$, in other words $P^2=(2-\sqrt{-5})$.

---

Leaving my earlier arguments showing how the approach evolved.

---

From where you are in your last line you can continue as follows:

First verify that
$$3\cdot 3=9=(2+\sqrt{-5})(2-\sqrt{-5})\in(2-\sqrt{-5}).$$

Then check that
$$
3(1+\sqrt{-5})=3+3\sqrt{-5}=(2-\sqrt{-5})(-1+\sqrt{-5})\in(2-\sqrt{-5}).
$$

Together with your last line these two observation prove the reverse inclusion
$$
(3,1+\sqrt{-5})^2\subseteq(2-\sqrt{-5})
$$
so you are done.

---

The above (or the approach in Bill Dubuque's answer) is the kind of argument you can use, when first starting with this topic. A little bit later, after you have learned about class groups and such, you can take advantage of the fact the class number of this field is $h=2$. An immediate consequence is that the square of **any** ideal is principal.
 Therefore $P^2$ is of index $3^2=9$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. This means that - without any further calculations whatsoever - we know that
$$
P^2=(a+b\sqrt{-5}),
$$
where $a,b$ are rational integers and
$$
N(a+b\sqrt{-5})=a^2+5b^2=9.
$$
This leaves us the possibilities (up to sign) $a=3,b=0$ or $a=2,b=\pm1$. But you already had the key idea that $2-\sqrt{-5}\in P^2$, implying that $P^2\subseteq (2-\sqrt{-5})$,
so the claim follows.

Comment: Thanks for the higher viewpoint! Can I ask how you know $P$ is of index 3 in the ring of integers? The only relevant thing I know is the index of a principal ideal in the ring of integers is equal to the norm of the generator over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Sorry about not replying to you question right away. IIRC one of the early examples of prime factorizations in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is the fact that $P$ and its conjugate ideal $\overline{P}=(3,1-\sqrt{-5})$ are the primes lying above the rational prime $3$. In other words $$P\overline{P}=(3).$$ Because $(3)$ is of index $9$, and as conjugates $P$ and $\overline{P}$ have the same index, they must both have index three.

Comment: The same conclusion can be reached by observing that any number $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ is congruent to $a-b$ modulo $1+\sqrt{-5}$. And of course $a-b$ is then congruent to one of $0,1,2$ modulo $3$. So modulo $P$ there are at most three cosets. Of course, $P$ does not contain any units, so the number of cosets cannot be less than three.