# Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that if $b = qa + r, q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(r,a)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

This is a lemma from Rotman's book *Advanced Modern Algebra*:

Let $a$ and $b$ be integers (and so are $q$ and $r$). I need to prove that if $b = qa + r$, then $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(r,a)$.

Not sure how to approach the proof.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95799/why-is-gcda-b-gcdb-r-when-a-qb-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** : At first we consider the simpler case $r=0$. I will note $D(x,y)$ the set of the common divisors of $x$ and $y$.

**Case 1** : If $r=0$, then $b=aq$ so $gcd(a,b)=a$.

**Case 2** : If $r \neq 0$. Let $d$ a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, $r=b-aq$, so $d$ divides $r$. So $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $r$. $D(a,b) \subseteq D(a,r)$.

Let $e$ a common divisor of $a$ and $r$, $b = aq+r$, so $e$ divides $b$. So $e$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$. $D(a,r) \subseteq D(a,b)$.

So $D(a,b)=D(a,r)$. The largest element of $D(a,b)$ is also the largest element of $D(a,r)$. So $gcd(a,r)=gcd(b,a)$.

Comment: There's no need to divide the proof into two cases; in the second part you nowhere use the fact that $r\ne0$. The only problem might arise when $a=0$, but that's an easy case, because then $r=b$.

Comment: Your right I will just say that it is a simpler case.