# How to prove $\gcd(a-bc, b) =\gcd(a,b)$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I'm not really sure how to approach the problem, since I'm not really sure I understand the mechanisms why it is true aside from putting some numbers in and see that it works.

Qualitatively, I'd try a proof by contradiction, trying to show that $\gcd(a-bc, b) \neq \gcd(a,b)$ and use some prime attribute to contradict the assumption.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95799/why-is-gcda-b-gcdb-r-when-a-qb-r

Comment: Redirecting the duplication  to the higher quality target Martin found. Sorry about the seesaw.

Answer (score 3):

Let $d$ be a common divisor of $a-bc$ and $b$, then there exists integers $q_1$ and $q_2$ such that $a-bc=dq_2$ and $b=dq_1$. Hence $a-bc = a - (dq_1)c = dq_2$, thus $a=d(q_1c+q_2)$. It follows that $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Conversely, suppose that $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, you have to show that $d$ is a common divisor of $a-bc$ and $b$.

Comment: @nnov: Thank for the edit, I missed that :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Try proving that each term of your equality divides the other, i.e.
$$\gcd(a-bc, b) | \gcd(a,b) \mbox{ and }   \gcd(a,b) |\gcd(a-bc, b)$$

Comment: My sincere apologies, I downvoted completely by accident (fat fingers). Since I was locked out, I had to make an edit with a few spaces to reverse it to an upvote. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Deepak no problem, done that before too :)

Answer (score 3):

The common divisors of $a$ and $b$ are the common divisors of $a-bc$ and $b$ and vice versa , because if $d|b$ then $d|a$ if and only if $d|a-bc$.

This immediately proves the claim.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,d\mid b\ $ then $\ d\mid a\!-\!bc\iff d\mid a.\,$ Hence $\,a\!-\!bc,\,b\,$ and $\,a,b\,$ have the same set $S\,$ of *common* divisors $\,d,\,$ so they have the same *greatest* common divisor $(= \max\, S).$

Answer (score 0):

This follows directly from the "Division Algorithm". Note that if 
$$
a=\overbrace{q}^{quotient}b+\overbrace{r}^{remainder},
$$ 
where $0\leq r<b$, then 
$$
a-bc=\overbrace{(q-c)}^{quotient}b+\overbrace{r}^{remainder}
$$
In other words, the remainder we get after dividing $a-bc$ by $b$ is the same as after dividing $a$ by $b$. Hence
$$
\gcd(a-bc,b)=\gcd(a,b)
$$