# gcd(m,n) = gcd(n, m mod n)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

The Following exercise is driving me nuts as I'm the only one who does not seem to get it:

Prove the equality $\gcd(m, n) = \gcd(n,m\bmod n)$ for every pair of positive
integers m and n.

Most proofs just show that $m\bmod n$ is divisible by $\gcd(m, n)$ but I do not get why that would mean the equality holds.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This is basically the same question as [Why is $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)$ when $a = qb + r$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/95799)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $m = qn + r$, where $q,r$ are integers and $0 \le r < n$.

Let $d = \text{gcd}(m,n)$ and let $e = \text{gcd}(n,r)$. The goal is to show $d=e$.

First we show $d|e$ . . .

\begin{align*}
&d = \text{gcd}(m,n)\\[6pt]
\implies\;&d|m \text{ and }d|n\\[6pt]
\implies\;&d|(m - qn)\\[6pt]
\implies\;&d|r
\end{align*}

Since $d|n$ and $d|r$, it follows that $d|\text{gcd}(n,r)$, hence $d|e$.

Next we show $e|d$ . . .
\begin{align*}
&e = \text{gcd}(n,r)\\[6pt]
\implies\;&e|n \text{ and }e|r\\[6pt]
\implies\;&e|(qn+r)\\[6pt]
\implies\;&e|m
\end{align*}

Since $e|m$ and $e|n$, it follows that $e|\text{gcd}(m,n)$, hence $e|d$.

Sincd $d|e$ and $e|d$, it follows that $d = e$.

Comment: brilliantly clear prove many thanks!

Comment: @quasi what does the vertical bar stand for? $|$

Comment: @csandreas1: In this context, the vertical bar is the _divisibility_ symbol. The notation $a|b$ is read as "$a$ divjdes $b$" and it means "$a$ is a divisor of $b$", or equivalently, expressed as an equation, it means $b=ax$, for some integer $x$.

Comment: @quasi Hello i want to ask how do you know d|m-qn from  d|n and d|m , by what theorem?

Comment: @fiksx: If $d|a$ then $d|ac$ for all $c$, hence from $d|n$ we get $d|qn$. Also, if $d|a$ and $d|b$ then $d|(a+b)$ and $d|(a-b)$, hence from $d|m$ and $d|qn$, we get $d|(m-qn)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,d\mid n\,$ then $\,d\mid m\!\iff\! d\mid \overbrace{m\bmod n}^{ \large m \ -\ q\,n} =:\bar m.\,$ Thus $\,n,m\,$ and $\,n,\, \bar m\,$ have the same set $S$ of *common* divisors $d,\,$ so they have the same *greatest* common divisor $(= \max S).$

Comment: It remains true if we replace $\,m\bmod n\,$ by any $\bar m$ such that $\,\bar m\equiv m\pmod{\! n},\,$ i.e. $\,n\mid \bar m - m.\ \ $