# trying to prove that if m, n and a are in the integers then $gcd(m, n) = gcd(n, m - an)$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

So in trying to formulate this proof, based on the statement that:

$gcd(m, n): ∀m, n, a ∈ \mathbb Z,∃ e \in \mathbb N, ((e|m ∧ e|n) ∧ (∀ d ∈ \mathbb N, d|n ∧ d|m \Rightarrow d\leq e))$

I've attempted to translate the following statement into predicate logic and I've been on the fence in terms of what translation is actually correct: $gcd(m, n) = gcd(n, m-an)$.

What I have now is:

$∀m, n, a ∈ \mathbb Z, ∃ e ∈ \mathbb N,((e|m ∧ e|n) ∧(∀ d ∈ N, d|n ∧ d|m => d≤e)) $

$∧ ∃ f ∈ \mathbb N, (f|n ∧ f|(m−an)) ∧ (∀ d ∈ \mathbb N, d|n ∧ d|m−an) \Rightarrow d ≤ f) \Rightarrow (f=e))$

There are 2 assumptions that I'm allowed to use:

1) $∀a,b,c ∈ \mathbb N, a|b ∧ b|c ⇒ a|c$

2) $∀a,b,d∈\mathbb Z, d|a ∧ d|b \Rightarrow  ∀p, q ∈ \mathbb Z, d|(pa+qb)$

There are a few things that I've tried, but it feels like the proofs I've been able to formulate are lacking. Is my initial translation incorrect? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: If you're asking for a proof, then this has been asked and answered *many* times before, e.g. [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95799/242), so the question will be closed as a duplicate. If instead you're asking something else, e.g. how to formulate something precisely in first order logic, then please make that request explicit.

Comment: Please, use latex and not Unicode

Comment: " I've attempted to translate the following statement into predicate logic "  why?  Will that make this easier for you to solve? Or is that part of the requirement?  Is this a number theory question or a predicate logic question.

Answer (score 1):

Call $\ d=\mathrm{gcd}(m,n)$. Then $d\vert m$ and $d\vert n$, this implies that 
$$ d\vert m-an$$ for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. So, $d$ satisfies
$$ d\vert  n\ \ \text{and} \ \ d\vert (m-an)$$
this means that $d$ is a common divisor of $n$ and $m-an$. Suppose that $x$ is also a common divisor of $n$ and $m-an$. Thus, $x\vert n$ implies $x\vert an$. So, $x\vert an$ and $x\vert m-an$. Hence $x\vert(an+(m-an))=m$. Finally, as $d=\mathrm{gcd}(m,n)$ we have:
$$x\vert m \ \text{and}\ \ x\vert n\ \Longrightarrow\ x\vert d$$