# Confusion regarding the concluding lines to the $GCD(a,b) = GCD(b,r)$ proof...why can we conclude the divisors are all part of the same set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-algorithm

As my title suggests, the last few lines of the proof to the following theorem:

If $a=bq+r$, then $gcd(a,b)=gcd(b,r)$

are not sitting well with me. I understand completely the preceding remarks in the proof...namely:

$x|a \land x|b \Rightarrow x|r$

and

$x'|b \land x'|r \Rightarrow x'|a$

However, I fail to see that this implies $x'$ and $x$ belong to the same set...which is the crucial 'insight' that precedes the ultimate steps of proving the theorem.

I've tried a few different ways of visualizing these sets...specifically:

Let $D = \{d\ \epsilon \ \mathbf Z | \ \ d|a \}$   i.e. $D$ is the set of all divisors of $a$

Let $E = \{e\ \epsilon \ \mathbf Z | \ \ e|b \}$ i.e. $E$ is the set of all divisors of $b$

Let $F = \{f\ \epsilon \ \mathbf Z | \ \ f|r \}$ i.e. $F$ is the set of all divisors of $r$

Let $G = D \cap E$

Let $H = E \cap F$

Therefore:

if $x|a \land x|b$, then $x \ \epsilon \ G $

and

if $x'|b \land x'|r$, then $x' \ \epsilon\  H$

I note that $x'$ and $x$ are clearly **both** in the set $E$, as they are both divisors of of $b$. Additionally, by my first two remarks:

$x\ \epsilon \ F$ and $x'\ \epsilon\ D$

This generates the resulting odd illustration, where both $x$ and $x'$ need to be simultaneously present in two different locations (which I have depicted as occurring in one of four possible different ways):

[image: First Way]

[image: Second Way]

[image: Third Way]

[image: Fourth Way]

(Sorry for all of the pictures). So, obviously, these elements can't be in two places at once. To me, intuitively, the only way this can *actually* (within the limits of the rule *you can only be in one place at a time*) happen is if the set containing $x$ is identically the same set that contains $x'$. Unfortunately, I am uncomfortable with that statement. Is there a proof of what I am regarding as "intuitive"? Further, **does this mean that the set $G$ and the set $H$ are the same set even though they are fundamentally constructed in different ways?** Such  a situation could be expressed by the following picture:

[image: 3D Intersection]

However, I am still uncertain of whether or not I can "accept" this based purely on the idea of its visual appeal. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) shows $\,d\mid a,b\iff d\mid b,r\ $ so $\,a,r\,$ and $\,b,r\,$ have the same set $S$ of *common* divisors $d,\,$ so they have the same *greatest* common divisors $(= \max S).\,$ You don't need diagrams to grok that.

Comment: @BillDubuque Do you mean "so $a,b$ and $b,r$ have same set $S$..." in above comment?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, that's a typo.