# Proving that a quantity is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a,b\geq 1$. How does one prove that $\dfrac{a+b\choose b}{a+b}$ is an integer?

I tried substituting for $a$ and $b$ using $ax+by=1$ for some $x,y$, also tried expanding but i cant figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: $a$ and $a+b$ are relatively prime, and $$a\binom{a+b}a=(a+b)\binom{a+b-1}{a-1}\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elaboration of Brian's hint.

Note that $\gcd(a,a+b)=\gcd(a,b)$. See [Why $\gcd(qb+r,b)=\gcd(b,r)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95799)

Also,
$$
\binom{a+b}{b}=\frac{(a+b)!}{a!b!} = \frac{a+b}{a}\cdot\frac{(a+b-1)!}{(a-1)!b!}
=\frac{a+b}{a}\cdot\binom{a+b-1}{a-1} 
$$So
$$
a\binom{a+b}{b} = (a+b)\binom{a+b-1}{a-1}\;.
$$
It follows that $r\mid pq$, where
$$
\quad r =a+b,\quad p = a,\quad q=\binom{a+b}{b}
$$
Now you can apply Bézout's identity to get $xp+yr = 1$. Multiplying $q$ on both sides as in the proof of Euclid's lemma to conclude that we must have $r\mid q$.

Comment: I guess one doesn't even need Bézout's identity. As you said, $r$ divides $pq$ but $r$ doesn't divide $p$ so it must divide $q$

Comment: @hello_123: the fact that "$r\mid pq$ and $\gcd(r,p)=1$ implies $r\mid q$" requires a proof. See also [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#:~:text=In%20number%20theory%2C%20Euclid's%20lemma,those%20integers%20a%20and%20b.). One way to do it is use Bezout's identity. One can probably use something else; e.g., fundamental theorem of arithmetic (the proof of which comes from Euclid's lemma).