# Modular Congruences

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

I have the following exercise.

If $ abc \equiv b \pmod{m} $ and $ \gcd{(a,m)} = 1 $, then $ ac \equiv 1 \pmod{m} $.

My attempt.

From $ abc \equiv b \pmod{m} $, by definition, $ abc - b = b ( ac - 1 ) = mh $.

Now: if $ b \mid h $, then $ ac - 1 = mk \implies ac \equiv 1 \pmod {m} $; if $ b \mid m $... I don't know what to do...

Ideas? Other solutions?
Thanks.

Comment: You need $\,\gcd(\color{#c00}m,b) = 1\,$ (not $\,\gcd(\color{#c00}a,b)= 1$) to cancel $b$ modulo $\,m.\,$ Probably a typo.

Comment: You are partially right. Is is $ \gcd{(a,m)} = 1 $. Edit done.

Comment: That's still incorrect, e.g. let $\, m = b(ac-1).\ \ $

Comment: I don't know... I'm newbie with number theory. I checked and the text says $\gcd{(a,m)}=1$ as hypotesis. I don't know...

Comment: Then it's a typo, as I surmised in the first comment. In any case the correct version is a diupe of many other questiuons.

Comment: See the linked questibns for the general theory (which applies when $\,\gcd(m,b) = 1\,$ the only hypothesis that makes the result generally true).

Comment: I don't know what to say. As I said, I'm newbie and I don't know how ti undestand if there Is a typo in text or not. All I can say is that the text says "$\gcd{(a,m)}=1$". If you say that it is not correct, I believe you.

Comment: I don't think "believing an expert" is the right attitude of learning math.

Comment: @GNU There is no "proof by authority" since I gave a simple counterexample a few  comments above. Further, the linked dupes give the general solvability / cancelability  criterion - which also makes it clear that the typo version is not correct.

Comment: I agree. You are right. I'm sorry.

Comment: @user1988 No need to apologize - it's not your fault there is a typo in your text.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque
With your counterexample $m = b ( ac - 1 )$, I take numbers like $60 = 4 ( 8 \cdot 2 - 1 )$ and similar: I was not able to chose numbers such that $\gcd{(a,m)}=1$ starting from $m = b ( ac - 1 )$. I'm sorry. My fault.

Comment: Note that if $\,\color{#c00}{m\mid ac\!-\!1}\,$ and $\,m = b(ac-1)\,$ then $\,1 = b\color{#c00}{(ac-1)/m},\,$ so $\,b = \pm1,\,$ so choosing $b$ otherwise yields infinitely many counterexamples. Conversely, it is clearly true when $\,b = \pm1\,$ (no gcd hypothesis is needed)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Starting from $ m \mid ac - 1 $, I have $ ac - 1 = mk $, so from $ 1 = b ( ac - 1 ) / m $ I have $ 1 = bk $. At this point it should be $ b = \pm 1 $ and $ k = \mp 1 $. Right?

Comment: Note that $\,\gcd(a,m) = \gcd(a,abc\!-\!b) = \gcd(a,b)\,$ so you need to choose $\,a,b\,$ coprime to satisfy your constraint $\,\gcd(a,m)=1;\ $ e.g. for  $\,a=1,\,b=2\,$ your claim says that $\bmod 2c\!-\!2\!:\ 2c=2 \Rightarrow c=1,\,$ true iff $\,c=1,\,$ e.g. for $\,c=2\,$ it says $\bmod 2\!:\ 4\equiv2\Rightarrow\, 2\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,2\mid 1,\,$ contradiction. (this is a reply to your 2nd last comment)

Comment: I can't understand why $ \gcd(a,m) = \gcd(a,abc-b) = \gcd(a,b) $. Is that true in general or I need the hypothesis $ \gcd(a,m) = 1 $?

Comment: [By Euclid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) $\,n\equiv \color{#c00}{\bar n} \pmod{\!a}\Rightarrow \gcd(a,n) = \gcd(a,\color{#c00}{\bar n}).\,$ Above $\,n = abc\!-\!b\equiv \color{#c00}{-b}\pmod{\!a}\,$ so Euclid $\Rightarrow\,\gcd(a,abc\!-\!b) = \gcd(a,\color{#c00}{-b})=\gcd(a,b)\ \ $

Comment: OK. I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This is incorrect.  Take $(a,b,c,m) = (1,2,3,4)$ as a counterexample: We have $\gcd(a,m) = \gcd(1,4) = 1$ and $$abc \equiv 3! \equiv 6 \equiv 2 \equiv b \pmod4,$$ but $$ac \equiv 3 \cdot 1 \equiv 3 \not\equiv 1 \pmod 4.$$

Comment: Please don't give answers till the question is clarified...(see the comments).

Comment: @BillDubuque Why not?  You may see [this meta answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/322/290189) for handling false statements.  The question statement is clear.

Comment: Questions based on typos generally add no value to the site (esp. when they are dupes of FAQs when the typo is corrected).

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample.

Comment: @user1988 You're welcome.

Comment: @BillDubuque [This meta answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19912/290189) suggests something quite different.

Comment: @user1988 In case it is not clear, this answer is the special case $\,a,b,c = 1,2,3\,$ of the general counterexample I gave $3$ minutes prior in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960588/modular-congruences?noredirect=1#comment8167845_3960588), viz. $\,m = b(ac\!-\!1)\,$ with $\,1=(a,b)\,[=(a,m)]\ \ $