# Proving that, for integers $n$, $m$, $p$, if $n| 72m–p$ and $n|8m$, then $n|p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to write a proof but I have been stuck for the past few hours trying to make progress.

I have to prove that

> For all integers $n$, $m$, and $p$, if $n| (72m–p)$ and $n| (8m)$, then $n|p$.

I tried substituting $72m-p$ for $x$, and $8m$ for $y$, but I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: $72m=9\cdot 8m$. If $n \mid a $ and $n \mid b$ then $n \mid ax+by$ for any integers $x,y$. Note that $p = 9\cdot 8m-(9\cdot 8m-p)$.

Comment: To prove if  $\,n\mid 8m\,$ then $\,n\mid 9(8m)-p\Rightarrow n\mid p\,$ see the methods in first dupe for proofs via divisibility laws, and see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) in the second dupe for congruence based proofs and conceptual remarks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${\displaystyle 72m-p\equiv 0{\pmod {n}}}$$
$${\displaystyle 9(8m)\equiv p{\pmod {n}}}$$
$${\displaystyle 8m\equiv 0{\pmod {n}}}$$
$${\displaystyle \text{Therefore: }9(0)\equiv p{\pmod {n}}}$$
$${\displaystyle p\equiv 0{\pmod {n}}}$$
$$\rightarrow n|p$$

Comment: I dont understand how the mod works or why everything is equal to 0

Comment: @CacklingMuse An equivalence under (mod n) means the LHS and the RHS have equal remainders upon being divided by n. Since n divides $72m-p$ and $8m$ then we can say they are both equal to 0 mod n. Using this we can rearrange to find p=0 (mod n), which means p divided by n yields remainder 0, hence p is divisible by n.