# Is this a valid proof for $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b,r),\ r = a-bq$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let
$ a \in \mathbb{N}$, $ b \in \mathbb{N}_0 $, $ r \in \mathbb{N}_0 $, $ q\in \mathbb{N} $ and $ b \leq a$ so that $$a = bq + r $$with $$ 0 \leq  r \lt b$$

Proof:

Let $ D = \{d \in \mathbb{Z} \vert ~  d \mid a \text{ and } d \mid b \}$ and Let $ D' = \{d \in \mathbb{Z} \vert ~ d \mid b \text{ and } d \mid r \}$

Let $ x \in D  $, so that $x \mid a$ and $x \mid b$:

$$ a = bq +r 
 $$
$$ a - bq  = r 
 $$

So $x \mid a-bq=r$ so $x \mid r$

Let $$ x \in D',  $$ so that $x \mid b$ and $x \mid r$:

$$ a = bq +r $$

So $x \mid b$ and $x \mid r$ but also $x \mid a$ and since $$ a \in D$$

$$ \gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b,r)$$

Any critique? Did i proved it somehow in a correct way? If not, could you show me what i did wrong or how to do it properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `$x$` for in-line notation $x$. Use `$$x$$` for centred $x$, like so: $$x$$

Comment: @Shaun updated. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: The proof looks correct to me.  You proved that the set of common divisors of both pairs is identical, from which it follows that the smallest element of those sets also must be the same.

Comment: @RobertShore the only thing that bothers me is the part with 0 ≤ r < b and the definition b≤a. It feels to me like i have to include that somewhere, but i don't know really where.

Comment: Did you mean to write $a \in D$ or did you mean $x \in D$?  They are both true I don't see how $a\in D$ leads to your conclusion. ..... "It feels to me like i have to include that somewhere, but i don't know really where"  It's not required.  If $a= bn + s$ then $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b,s)$ regardless of how big $a$ and $s$ are.  The only reason those are specified is to show it is true for the unique remainder $r$ (it's also true of the $s= r + Mb$ for any $r$ plus some multiple of $b$)... Basically an number $s$ and any $s+Mb$ will have the exact same factors in common with $b$.

Comment: The hypotheses $0 \le r < b$ and $b < $ are not relevant here. They become useful when you want to iterate the construction to calculate $\gcd(a, b)$ (Euclid's algorithm).

Comment: The proof shows that if $\,a = bq+r\,$ for $\,q,r\in\Bbb Z,\,$ then $\,x\mid a,b\Rightarrow x\mid r,\,$ $\rm \color{#c00}{thus}$ $\,D\subseteq D',\,$ i.e. $\,{\rm CD}(a,b)\subseteq {\rm CD}(b,r),\,$ for $\,\rm CD := $ set of common divisors (you forgot to state the conclusion after $\rm \color{#c00}{thus}),\,$ and similarly $\,{\rm CD}(b,r)\subseteq {\rm CD}(a,b),\,$ so the CD sets are equal, so they have equal greatest elements, i.e. equal GCDs. This is a very common proof, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) the linked dupe for a concise proof.