# Prove gcd(x,y) = gcd(x-y,y) for x > y

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Prove gcd(x,y) = gcd(x-y,y) for x > y
Here is my work so far:

If gcd(x,y) = d, then we can denote x = ad , y = bd, so x - y = (ad - bd) = d(a - b), so (x-y) is a multiple of d, so gcd(x -y, y) = gcd(d(a - b), bd) = d, so gcd(x-y, y) = gcd(x,y).

My teacher challenged it by asking to show why gcd(d(a - b), bd) = d.

I think that gcd(d(a - b), bd) = d if gcd(a-b, b) = 1 --> gcd(a,b) = 1,

But I need some more help as to why this occurs, or if their is a simpler method of proving gcd(x,y) = gcd(x-y,y) for x > y

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: @Knocker379 Why not? Yours is the same question, just with $q=-1, r=x, b=y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $z \mid x$ and $z \mid y$. Then write $x = az$, $y = bz$. Then $x - y = az - bz = (a - b) z$, so $z \mid x - y$. So every common factor of $x$ and $y$ is a common factor of $x - y$ and $y$.

Now suppose $z \mid x - y$ and $z \mid y$. Then write $x - y = az$, $y = bz$. Then $x = (x - y) + y = az + bz = (a + b) z$, so $z \mid x$. So every common factor of $x - y$ and $y$ is a common factor of $x$ and $y$.

Since $x, y$ and $x - y, y$ have the same set of common factors, they must have the same gcd.

Comment: @Knocker379 I literally just proved that. It's the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks it took me a second to get that

Comment: Notice the typographical difference between $x | y$ (coded as `x | y`) and $x\mid y$ (coded as `x\mid y`). Also notice what $x\nmid y$ looks like (coded as `x\nmid y`) as opposed to something like $x\not|y$ (coded as `x\not|y`). $$ \begin{align} & x\mid y \\ {} \\ & x\nmid  y \\ {} \\ & x | y \\ {} \\ & x\not|y \end{align} $$

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score -1):

- First prove that every divisor that $x$ and $y$ have in common is a divisor of $x-y.$
- Then prove that every divisor that $x-y$ and $y$ have in common is a divisor of $x.$

Thus the set of common divisors of $x$ and $y$ is the same as the set of common divisors of $x-y$ and $y.$

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque : I'm not aware of any duplication of anything by this answer.

Comment: Did you even look?  It's a special case of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242), and likely hundreds of others, as is the question. I don't know how any experienced user could conceive that this question (and answer) was not a dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque : I didn't look since you didn't provide a link. Until you did.

Comment: @BillDubuque : I regard it as an improvement over the answer to which you linked, since it's simpler. Making things simple takes some work and is worthwhile.

Comment: That answer is the accepted answer in the linked dupe on the qiuestion, so it's not clear why you did not look there. It is hardly "some work" to specialize $q=-1$.

Comment: @BillDubuque : There wasn't any linked duplicate at the time I posted this answer.

Comment: Please follow the link in my first comment to the meta post. Answering obvious dupes like this will likely result in suspension (and already has for many users who continue to do so after being notified about such).