# How to prove that $\gcd(m^2,m+n) = \gcd(n^2,m+n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

How can we prove that $\gcd(m^2,m+n) = \gcd(n^2,m+n)$?

My try:
$$
\gcd(m^2,m+n) = \gcd\left[m^2=m\cdot \left(m+n\right)-mn\right] = \gcd(m+n,mn)$$
But I don't think it'll help me for the future, there is another way maybe?

Comment: Why it doesn't help you for the future? It's a good solution, I think.

Comment: @Xavi Note that the central term doesn't make sense. Can you fix it to display what you want?

Comment: By [gcd mod reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) in the linked dupe: $\,\gcd(m^2,m+n) = \gcd(n^2,m+n)\,$ by $\,m^2\equiv n^2\pmod{m+n},\,$ since $\,m+n\mid m^2-n^2,\,$ or, more *arithmetically* 
by  $\!\bmod m+n\!:\ m\equiv -n\Rightarrow m^2\equiv (-n)^2\equiv n^2.\  $ More generally this shows $\gcd(f(m),m+n) = \gcd(f(-n),m+n)\,$ for any polynomial $f(x)$ with *integer* coefs, since the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\Rightarrow f(m)\equiv f(-n)\pmod{m+n}\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @WhatsUp said, you can continue this to a solution.

$$ \gcd(m+n,mn)=\gcd(m+n,-mn)$$
$$=\gcd(m+n,-mn+n(m+n))=\gcd(m+n,n^2)$$

Comment: Or more directly from what OP has, similarly $ \gcd(n^2, m+n) = \gcd(m+n, mn) $, so these values are equal.  (I'm guessing that's why @WhatsUp said "it's a good solution" as opposed to "It's a good start".)

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).