# $\gcd(a,b)=1$ from $2\min(a,b)-\max(a,b)=p$ where $p$ is odd prime

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, integers

Let $a,b$ be odd positive integers.

Suppose we have
$$2\min(a,b)-\max(a,b)>0$$
$$2\min(a,b)-\max(a,b)=p$$
$$\min(a,b)\ne0\operatorname{mod}p$$
where $p$ is odd prime number.

Then I conjecture that
$$\gcd(a,b)=1$$

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: Assume $a≤b$.  So $2a-b=p$  If some prime $q$ divided $\gcd(a,b)$ then we'd have $q\,|\, p$, so....

Comment: By $\,a,b\,$ symmetry, wlog $a\le b$ so the hypotheses become $[\![1]\!]\ \ldots, \ $ $[\![2]\!]\ \ 2a-b = p,\ $ $[\![3]\!]\ \ p\nmid a,\,$ so $\,(a,b) = (a,2a-p)\overset{\rm\color{#c00} R} = (a,-p) = 1\,$ by $\,p\nmid a\,$ and $\,\rm\color{#c00} R = $ [gcd mod Reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WLOG, assume $b \geq a$. Then your second condition says that $2a = b + p$. Now suppose that $q$ is a prime that divides $a$. If it also divided $b$, then it would also have to divide $p$; but then we would have to have $q = p$. But your third condition says that $p \not\mid a$. Thus there is no prime that divides both $a$ and $b$, so $\gcd(a, b) = 1$.

Note that you do not need the first requirement, nor the requirement that $a, b$ are odd.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: I do not believe that this is a duplicate from the original asker's point of view. Connecting the two questions is harder than solving the problem.

Comment: "Connecting them" is trivial algebra - see my comment on the question.

Comment: The question is also trivial algebra.