# Why are we able to use a particular value and assume that it applies to all other cases in algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was working on a question and a though came across my mind.

In the question, we had to prove that if n is odd, the gcd(3n, 3n + 2) = 1. So what I did was I said let a = gcd(3n, 3n + 2). Then we know a | 3n and a | 3n + 2 so a must divide any linear combination of 3n and 3n + 2, i.e., a | y(3n) + z(3n+2). Now, suppose y =-1 and z = 1 then a | 2 and so a must only equal 1 as n is odd and so a ≠ 2.

My question is, why are we allowed to take a particular value of y = -1 and z =1 and say that a divides a particular linear combination and then say that the rule that comes from that particular case, applies to all other cases? I.e., why can we say that because the a | 2 and so a must equal 1, then the gcd = 1. What if the linear combination was divisible by some other value that also divides 3n and 3n + 2?

Because I know that it does work through trial and error of various values, but I want to know why. Is there some sort of mathematical principal I am unaware of?

If someone could shed some light on this, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

P.s.My professors working out has been attached below.

3. Prove that if n is odd, then gcd(3n,3n+2)=1. What if n is even?

Solution. Let d = gcd(3n,3n + 2). Since d | 3n and d | 3n + 2, it follows that d | (3n+2)−3n = 2. Since the only divisors of 2 are 1 and 2, it follows that d = 1 or 2. But if n is odd, then 3n is also odd, so we cannot have d=2(since d|3n). It follows that d = 1 if n is odd. (If n is even, then 2 divides both 3n and 3n+2, so d = 2 in this case.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "must divide **any** linear combination", i.e. all possible combinations, and,  _in particular_, $y=-1, z=1$.

Comment: Yes, but how is it that we can say a = 1 and not any other higher value for other linear combinations?

Comment: I will make that clearer in my question. Sorry

Comment: @Oofy2000 "*assume that it applies to all other cases*" $\;-\;$ There is no such assumption in the proof you quote. It's just a series of direct implications. If you don't follow one of the steps, then ask about that specific step and explain what the problem is that you see with it.

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you

Comment: Via [Euclidean algorithm reduction step](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) $\,\gcd(m,m+2) = \gcd(m,2) = 2\,$ if $m$ is even, else $1$ for odd $m$ (as in OP when $m = 3n,\,$ for odd $n).\,$ Your professor is essentially repeating the proof of the linked Euclidean algorithm reduction step (in the special case of the OP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that might in some spaces be called the "axiom schema of replacement", and it boils down to:

- If a statement $P(x)$ is true for *all* values of $x$, then if you choose a value of $x$ then $P$ *must* be true when you substitute that value in.

It relates to proof by contradiction - if there is a value of $x$ you can choose that makes $P(x)$ false, then clearly $P(x)$ is not true for *every* value of $x$.

In this case, it means that since $a$ divides every linear combination of $3n$ and $3n+2$, then if we choose the most restrictive linear combination possible it will still be true that $a$ divides it. And since we happen to be able to make the value $(3n)(-1) + (3n+2)(1) = 2$, we know that $a$ still has to divide this linear combination, otherwise it doesn't divide *all* of them.

It doesn't matter if $a$ divides every *other* linear combination, because the theorem isn't "The GCD divides every linear combination except maybe one or two" - either it divides anything you can imagine, or it wasn't actually the GCD to begin with.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for that explanation. Absolutely brilliant. Thank you