# Let b, n be positive integers where n is prime. Then b|(4b+n) if and only if b=1 or b=n.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Do a two-part proof and use either direct or proof by contrapositive.

Let b, n be positive integers where n is prime.  Then b|(4b+n) if and only if b=1 or b=n.

I started with the if direction:
Assume b=1 or b=n.
Prove that b|(4b+n)
Case 1: Assume b=1
1|4+n
We know that n is a positive prime integer, therefore b|(4b+n)
Case 2: Assume b=n
Then b|(4b+n)=n|5n therefore b|(4b+n)

I'm getting stuck on the Only If direction.
Assume b|(4b+n)
Prove that b=1 or n.
Then bk=4b+n and k=4+$\frac{n}{b}$
Can I now state that we know that since n is a positive prime number, it is only divisible by b if b is n or 1? Or is this against the rules.

Comment: If $b$ divides $4b+n$, then can you prove that $b$ divides $n$ ?

Comment: Note $\,b\mid 4b+n\iff b\mid n\,$ By [divisibility mod reuction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) in the linked dupe.