# I don't see how to use Chinese Remainder Theorem and prime factorizations to solve this problem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $a$ is odd. I want to show that there are infinitely many $b$ for which $(a,b)=(a,b+1)=1$.

What I have done is this:

Let $b=ak+1$. Then $1=(-k)a+b$, and so $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
If $2=(-k)a+b'$, then $\gcd(b',a)=1$.

First of all, is this correct?

Secondly, my book says to use Chinese Remainder Theorem. How to apply CRT  to come up with $ak+1$ and $ak+2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but can be polished by saying after $2=-ka+(b+1)$ that since an integer linear combination of $a$ and $b+1$ sums to $2$, $(a,b+1)\mid2$, so that GCD is $1$ or $2$.

The book's proof begins with the prime power factorisation of $a$, noting that the factors will be at least $3$. By CRT we can compute infinitely many numbers $b$ that are $1$ modulo all of those factors, so $(a,b)=1$. But then $b+1$ is $2$ modulo all of those factors, so $(a,b+1)=1$ as well. This is a snazzier *presentation* than yours, but essentially the same *content* since $ak+1$ is $1$ modulo any factor of $a$ – your proof is more understandable.

Comment: Thanks. But is my proof correct?

Comment: @violet It is correct, actually.

Comment: @violet CRT is major overkill (not "snazzier") for this simple problem, since it can be simpler  deduced as you did, i.e. $\color{#c00}{1,2}$ are coprime to odd $\,a,\,$ so $\bmod a\!:\ b\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, b,b\!+\!1\equiv \color{#c00}{1,2}\,$ are also coprime to $\,a\ $ (clearer by [gcd mod reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) vs. your use of Bezout).

Comment: @violet Said more simply: if $\,b,b\!+\!1\,$ are coprime to $\,a\,$ then so too are $\,a\!+\!b,\,a\!+\!b\!+\!1,\,$ so continually adding $\,a\,$ yields infinitely many coprime pairs.