# Divisibility proof: if $10\mid a+b$ and $5\mid b$, then $5\mid a$

Tags: divisibility

I am trying to figure out whether it is true or false that if $10\mid a+b$ and $5\mid b$, then $5\mid a$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

I am trying to demonstrate it that it is a true statement like so:

$a+b=10q$ and $b=5q'$ therefore $a=5q''$

Substituting, we get that $5q''+5q'=10q$

Therefore, $5(q''+q')=10q$

Simplifying, $q''+q'=2q$

Therefore, $5k=10q$ ($k=q''+q'$) where $2\mid k$ proves that $10\mid 5k$, which means $10\mid5q''+5q'$, making the initial statement true.

Comment: Not following.  Using your notation, we get $a+5q'=10q$ which implies that $a=5\times(2q-q')$ which is all you need.

Comment: @lulu Understood, thank you!

Comment: If $10\mid a+b$, then $5\mid a+b.$.  If $5\mid a+b$ and $5\mid b,$ then $5\mid a$

Comment: I changed my proof, would it be valid this time? You have given me correct proofs but haven't said if mine was correct or not.

Comment: The structure of your proof seems wrong to me. "...therefore $a=5q''$..." seems to be assuming what you are trying to prove. You then conclude your "proof" with "$10 \mid 5q''+5q'$...". But this last is not what you are trying to prove. You're trying to prove that $5\mid a$.

Comment: You made the initial statement true, but you want to make the final statement $5\mid a$ (or $q''\in\mathbb Z$) true.

Comment: $5\mid a\!+\!b,\,b\,\Rightarrow\, 5\mid (a\!+\!b)-b = a\,$ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) in the linked dupe. $ \ \ $